# Problema al cambiar clase en Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola Amigos estoy tratando de cambiar la case de un botón para cada que le de click tendrá una clase diferente y me traerá una respuesta del servidor asíncrona con ajax exactamente para ese botón, resulta que la primer vez le doy click y al inspeccionar consola noto que si cambia la clase y al darle el segundo click no reacciona, parece que no reconociera la nueva clase, ese es mi código:

```js
$("#send").click(function(){
   $('#send').removeClass("btnuno").addClass("btndos");
});


$(".btndos").on('click',function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('funciono');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="send" class="btnuno">clik</button>
```

Comment: La nueva clase deberías asignarla desde el bloque `done`  o `success` de Ajax, debido a que las peticiones Ajax son asíncronas.

Comment: me cambia la clase , pero no me ejecuta el evento del nuevo nombre de la clase, pero en el html si quedo cambiado el nombre de la clase al darle el primer click, no logro comprender que sucedera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código presenta dos problemas:

- Siempre se ejecutará la primer función ya que dicho evento esta suscrito al elemento con `id="send"`.
- La segunda función no se ejecutará nunca. Ejecutarse el código se buscaran elementos cuya clase sea `btndos`, y no existe ninguno.

#### Solución:

Te recomiendo utilizar [delegación de eventos](https://osmancea.medium.com/delegaci%C3%B3n-de-eventos-del-dom-con-javascript-d28131d43686)

**Ejemplo:**

```js
// Cuando se haga click en el documento sobre un elemento 
// con class "btnuno"
$(document).on('click', ".btnuno", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("btnuno").addClass("btndos");
  console.log('Elemento "btnuno"')
});

// Cuando se haga click en el documento sobre un elemento 
// con class "btndos"
$(document).on('click', ".btndos", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("btndos").addClass("btnuno");
  console.log('Elemento "btndos"')
});
```

```css
.btnuno {
  background-color: red;
}

.btndos {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="send" class="btnuno">Click</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, funciona super bien llevaba todo el día haciendo pruebas pero no conocía el tema de delegación de eventos me pondré a estudiarlo, mil gracias por compartir tu conocimiento.